# Javascript CLONE element by user input data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When i clicked on **ADD** Button, it's appearing the text in the bellow but it's appearing the same column. here is 2 input field.

> 1. i have used :  `<input id="accordion_input" type="text"/>`
> 2. another one is : `<div id="accordion_body" class="panel-body"></div>`

[image]

> 

So i want, if i fill-up the **input** and **div** area & clicked ADD button then i should be appear and second time if i clicked on add button then it's should  be CLONE the First input data. The data must be showing on different column every clone part, not in the same column! Like the below snapshot:

[image]

```js
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#Add_btn').click(function() {
    $('#accordion_body').append($('#editableDiv').html());
    
    var x = $("#accordion_input").val();
    $("#accordion_title").append(x);
     });  
   });
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>404</title>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <input id="accordion_input" type="text">
  <div id="editableDiv" contenteditable=""></div><br/>
  <div id="acc_main" contenteditable="false" class="accordion-main">
    <div class="panel-group trash_removed" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" contenteditable="false">
   <div class="panel panel-default">
     <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne" contenteditable="false">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a id="accordion_title" style="display: block"></a>
    </h4>
    
    
    <div id="expandingCol" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne" style="display: block">
      <div id="accordion_body" class="panel-body"></div>
      
    </div>
    </br>
    
     </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button id="Add_btn">Add</button>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just wrap the content in a <p> tag? `$('#accordion_body').append("<p>" + $('#editableDiv').html() + "</p>");`

Answer (score -1):

Wrap the content in a `<p>` tag or insert a `<br/>` after each one.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It seems like what you want is to append the text on a new line each time, no?